# I need counts of unique combinations of 3 columns in a year

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have data table like this:

```
dept   sub-dept   class   submission-date
 ENG      CS        A       12-06-2012    
 ENG      CS        A       19-08-2012
 ENG      EE        A       02-04-2012
 ENG      CS        A       12-08-2013
 ENG      EE        A       02-06-2012
 SCI      PHY       B       11-04-2012
```

result must look like this:

```
dept   sub-dept   class     count    started-date   last-date
 ENG      CS        A         2       12-06-2012    19-08-2012
 ENG      EE        A         2       02-04-2012    02-06-2012
 ENG      CS        A         1       02-04-2013    02-04-2013
 SCI      PHY       B         1       11-04-2012    11-04-2012
```

In the first row (ENG,CS,A) the submission date is 12-06-2012, so I want to find how many rows are there with same combination that is ENG,CS,A within 12-06-2012 and 12-06-2013 (The first occurrence submission date should be considered as initial-date). Although 4th row has the same combination but does not lie in an year starting from first occurrence, so it should be represented separately (must not be included in count).
start date and last date are the first and last occurrences of the combinations within an year of first occurrences.
I'm doing this in MySQL (version -5.6). For this problem either basic mysql query or even stored procedure can be used.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT(), MIN()/MAX()

Comment: thanks for reply @Akina. Can you please elaborate this with a query or stored procedure?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the reply. I'm using MySQL (version 5.6)

Comment: What is datatype for column `submission-date`? Varchar?

Comment: hi @tcadidot0 not varchar. datatype of `submission-date` is **date**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE datasource (
  dept   CHAR(3),
  subdept   char(3),
  class   CHAR(1),
  submissiondate DATE
);

INSERT INTO DataSource (dept, subdept, class, submissiondate)
    VALUES ('ENG','CS','A','12-06-2012'),    
           ('ENG','CS','A','20120819'), -- MAKE Way for MDY format in database
           ('ENG','EE','A','02-04-2012'),
           ('ENG','CS','A','12-08-2013'),
           ('ENG','EE','A','02-06-2012'),
           ('SCI','PHY','B','11-04-2012');
```

*Query*

```sql
SELECT dept, subdept,c lass, COUNT(*) as cnt,
       MIN(Submissiondate) as started_date,
       MAX(Submissiondate) as last_date
FROM @DataSource
GROUP BY dept, subdept, class, YEAR(SubmissionDate)
```

*Result set*

```
+------+---------+-------+-----+--------------+------------+
| dept | subdept | class | cnt | started-date | last-date  |
+------+---------+-------+-----+--------------+------------+
| ENG  | CS      | A     |   2 | 2012-08-19   | 2012-12-06 |
| ENG  | CS      | A     |   1 | 2013-12-08   | 2013-12-08 |
| ENG  | EE      | A     |   2 | 2012-02-04   | 2012-02-06 |
| SCI  | PHY     | B     |   1 | 2012-11-04   | 2012-11-04 |
+------+---------+-------+-----+--------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
SELECT dept,sub_dept, class,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(subm_date,',',1) END AS started_date,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(subm_date,',',-1) 
            WHEN cnt=1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(subm_date,',',1) END AS last_date
FROM
(SELECT dept,sub_dept, class,
       GROUP_CONCAT(submission_date ORDER BY submission_date) subm_date, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM test
GROUP BY dept,sub_dept, class, YEAR(submission_date)) A
```

Fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hkiqbTK72MNwD3ymKSBoqF/0

Comment: thanks for the reply. But **count** is missing in the result. I need the count of number of occurrences in of same combination per year. (Please check the question again)